# how to List or highlight all class field used in a method of the same class?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, code-analysis, hotkeys

```
class A{
    private Object a;
    private Object a1;
    private Object a2;

    public void method(){
        // Tons of code
         code line using a;
        // Tons of code
         code line using a1;
    }
}
```

Now i want to list or highlight all fields used in method().. i.e result should be list of a, a1 or highlighted a,a1 in method body.

Comment: What is the benefit of knowing this?

Comment: I want to know how a method affects the state of the object.

Comment: If you double-click a or a1, it will highlight all references to either field (including those in the method body). If you select a or a1 and use ctrl+alt+h, you will have the list of all references of the selected field in the workspace (since it's private, all uses will be in your class). There is no way I know of to specifically retrieve "the list of fiels used in method x", those two are the closest things I know.

Comment: If you select a field/method eclipse shows you the occurrencies within the file. I recommend to right-click on of those highlights at the very right of the editor window and change the color to something you can actually see through the preferences dialog.